What gene could have a mutation that would cause this syndrome characterized by hyperempathy, liver disease, squeaky voice, and sumo-like physique?
My original character (OC) named Claudia Walsh Kondo is a Mexican woman of Irish (paternal grandfather), Sephardi Jewish (paternal grandmother), Yamato (maternal grandfather), and Ryukyuan (maternal grandmother) descend.
Claudia has a strange genetic disease named Lebeau-Seaman syndrome (LSS).
The symptoms of LSS are:

Hyperempathy (found in 100% of affected individuals), dyscalculia (found in 85% of affected individuals), autism (found in 70% affected individuals), ambidexterity (found in 60% of affected individuals) (28% of affected individuals are right-handed and 22% of affected individuals are left-handed), hyperacusis (found in 40% of affected individuals), and genius-level intellect (found in 25% of affected individuals);
High risk of liver disease, of amyloidosis, of cancer, and of thyroid disease;
Squeaky voice (which can be raspy, nasal, both, or neither) (people who are AFAB with this disease tend to sound like Pinkie Pie from My Little Pony, and people who are AMAB with this disease tend to sound like Mickey Mouse from Classic Disney Shorts);
Despite the EXTREMELY high-pitched voice, people with this disease tend to have a sumo-like physique (which means tall stature, high level of body fat, large muscles, and strong bones) (people who are AFAB with this disease have an average adult height of 1.88 metre tall and an average adult mass of 128 kilograms, and people who are AMAB with this disease have an average adult height of 1.98 metre tall and an average adult mass of 146 kilograms);
Both extremely high androgen levels and extremely high oestrogen levels, despite being less sensitive to both sex hormone types than the average human (however, this genetic disease does not usually cause infertility);
Low risk of heart disease, of diabetes, of osteoporosis, and of neurodegenerative disease;
Affected individuals are much more likely to be LGTBQIA+ than the average human being (50% of affected individuals are either bisexual, omnisexual, or pansexual, 30% of affected individuals are either asexual, autosexual, or abrosexual, 15% of affected individuals are homosexual/lesbian/gay, and only 5% are heterosexual/straight);
Finally, affected individuals have an average life expectancy of 72 years (74 years for people AFAB, and 70 years for people AMAB).

So, the question is: what gene mutation would causes most of all the mentioned symptoms?

I'll not down vote nor VTC because the structure of the question is OK... but you're asking for something remarkably specific with an equally remarkable list of arbitrary conditions. I'm not a geneticist by any stretch of the imagination, but I've had to deal with very complex things in my own industry and my spidey-sense about this suggests that it'll be a real stretch to come up with a combination of genes (I'm confident saying there won't be just one) that can rationalize that list. What's stopping you from ... (*Continued*)

... researching the genetics of the individual symptoms and finding 1-4 common-enough genes that you can throw in a bit of technobabble to cover the rest? (Thinking about that... one could almost down-vote for you're not having done that.)

"Affected individuals are much more likely to be LGTBQIA+" - given that being LGBTQIA+ isn't at all genetic by any study I've ever read (and I read quite a few), there is no such gene. Neither is intelligence (partial but not entirely genetic) - that depends greatly on environmental factors. You certainly won't find a single gene that does affect the actually-genetic components, though. Humans are complicated.

Is this a real syndrome? Or is this fictional? Dr Google doesn't seem to be familiar with it. If it's not a real syndrome, please edit your question, as this might be the difference between it being closed and being in need of some more work. Or even being fine as is!

You should link definitions to some of these terms since gender and queer studies are this site's kryptonite.

@Dmyt That's not completely true. Search the terms and you'll find most Qs are open and answered. The problem is three-fold. 1. SE enjoys a world-wide user base and much of the world still isn't comfortable with LGBT acceptance. 2. It's a political hot-potato and almost no users are willing to respect that. 3. Too many Qs along those lines are for the sake of social justice and not worldbuilding. Consequence: there are very few such questions - but most are open and answered. C'est la vie.

What you've described is a mash-up of lots of things. Why do you assume that there's a single over-arching term to describe that? Genetic conditions (or conditions with a genetic component) are very seldom moderated by a single gene, there's a whole mess of things that can be a factor in contributing to any single one of those attributes - i.e., there's no single mutation of a single gene, but more likely a confluence of mutations, omissions, duplications etc. numbering in the tens of thousands - or more.

You have a person. You have a genetic disease. You have effects of this genetic disease. Why isn't this good enough? Your disease is the gene mutation. If I'm your reader, I'm happy to take your description of the disease at face value. I don't want to know which gene you switched on or off - unless maybe if you're inventing a fictional biology textbook (and then I won't be a reader). Are you trying to ask if this disease is plausible?

Add to the challenges of this question is that symptoms of "genetic" problems could also arise due to epigenetic changes instead of pure DNA changes. The epigenetic changes simply expose preexisting variation in genes.

I've seen an estimate that every child has 100 mutations from their parent's genes. Which one caused which difference would be impossible to determine in most cases.

This boils down to "how to edit the dna so that a person becomes like this [set of symptoms]". This is way beyond our current tech level to answer AT ALL, except for a few very specific illnesses that actually are real and have successfully been linked to genes. This does not seem to be one of those.
So, a correct answer to this could maybe exists but you might have to wait at least a few decades, or centuries, for it.

Switch on Caps lock, close your eyes and type 3 or 4 letters and 1 or 2 numbers. There you have your gene. One in 1000 readers may try to look it up, and when they see it doesn't exist, they'll shrug and continue with the story.

The numbers for handedness add up to 110%. Do sufferers occasionally have an extra hand?-)

Seems like more of a mental illness than a gene issue

Frame challenge.
Flip your problem around: who or how many among your readers are going to raise an eyebrow two floors above their forehead and say "oh, gene Q4PW9#6 doesn't do that when mutated, this story is garbage!" before throwing it away?
X-men franchise have gone away with much more than real looking symptoms by just saying it's a mutation. What do you expect to gain by drilling so deep that you specify the gene involved in what you want your character to have?
Just say it's a mutation on a group of genes. It's a work of fiction, not a Nature, that you are writing.

This is very much why I asked my Meta question about worldbuilding parsimony. The "as realistic as possible" craze has left too many people not understanding where to draw the line between just-right and too-much. It's too bad we can't get everyone on a giant ZOOM meeting and teach a lesson about Chekhov's gun.

+1 - as any fan will be aware, Star Trek is about 95% handwaving and incomplete/inconsistent/nonexistent explanations and it’s still fun to watch.
